# Pass string to URL.

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have a String
NSString *const kAUrl = @"[http://www.google/start.php?show=best&usr=(here)&pwd=x](http://www.google/start.php?show=best&usr=%28here%29&pwd=x)";

and

i want to pass another String 
NSString *a = @"aa";

to above url at the place i have written  (here) in above url.

How can i pass it?

regards.

Comment: Why are you creating a string constant that you are then trying to modify?

Comment: I can't see the value of making an NSString constant, when it is already immutable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to encode the string suitable for URL using
the `NSString` instance method `-[stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:]`.

Then place into the URL using `-[stringWithFormat:]`.

For example:

```
-(NSURL*)showBestURLWithUser:(NSString*)user {
{
   user = [user stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
   static NSString* template = @"http://www.google/start.php?show=best&usr=%@&pwd=x";
   NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:template, user];
   return [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
}
```

Comment: is there a reason for using const?  the string is immutable in this state (without assigning a new object reference to it), as it is not a NSMutableString...

Comment: As far as I know, a const NSString* object you will not be able to re-assign a new NSString, and will only take a constant string (ie, @"string").

Comment: suggest me plz. i need const.

Comment: @shishir.bobby: I extended the example to use a constant string for the URL template, and framed it in a proper method context.

Answer (score 3):

Use NSString stringWithFormat:

```
NSString *a = @"hello";
NSString *kAUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google/start.php?show=best&usr=%@&pwd=x", a];
```

kAUrl now contains the contents of a where the %@ was.

---

Watch out though - if `a` contains any URL reserved characters (i.e. an `&` etc) it might break your url.

Comment: its wont work, since NSString *const a ;   a is const..it giving me error.plz suggest.

Comment: Why must it be a const? Just don't make it a const and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You would change your declaration to this:

```
NSString *kAUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google/start.php?show=best&usr=%@&pwd=x", a];
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

NSString *a = @"aa";

NSString *kAUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google/start.php?show=best&usr=%@&pwd=x",a];

kAUrl = [kAUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

job done.

Comment: wouldn't this encode the entire string as a URL? including URL protocol, etc portion?

Comment: why do you need the "const"??